# When does Nexus 3 generate the simple index for pypi repositories?

Tags: nexus3

I roughly scanned the sources of the `nexus-repository-pypi` plugin and found `PyPiHostedFacetImpl#getRootIndex()` which eventually generates a simple-html-index-file. But I couldn't find, where this is called.

How is the index creation triggered? Uploading an artifact doesn't do this. Requesting the index file (https://.../simple/foobar) doesn't create this (404). Rebuild index doesn't generate the file. What am I missing?

I am currently using Version `3.23.0-03` (I am aware this should be updated, but this is not in my responsibility at the moment).